# xml parse from mysqldump in php

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I'm  trying to parse this xml file to php.

http://www.san-isidro.net/appmovil/partenieve.xml

The problem are that i don't know to parse with this xml format obtained with mysqldump.

Can you help me to parsing `<field name="observaciones">` in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to walkthrough [`simplexml_load_file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) on PHP

Your code will be something like this

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.san-isidro.net/appmovil/partenieve.xml');
print_r($xml);
```

OUTPUT:

> SimpleXMLElement Object ( [database] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
>   [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => sanisidro ) [table_structure] =>
>   SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] =>
>   nuke_partenieve ) [field] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
>   [@attributes] => Array ( [Field] => id [Type] => int(10) [Null] => NO
>   [Key] => PRI [Default] => 0 [Extra] => [Comment] => ) ) [1](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) =>
>   SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [Field] => date
>   [Type] => date [Null] => NO [Key] => [Default] => 0000-00-00 [Extra]
>   => [Comment] => ) ) [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [Field] => espesor_max [Type] => text [Null] => NO [Key]
>   =>......